# javascript confirm asp.net button never submits?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, form-submit

i have a regular asp:button. I am working in .Net 3.5. I've tried adding a js confirm to the button with the OnClientClick attribute as well as adding in code-behind and the result is the same. No matter what the user clicks in the confirm pop-up the form will not submit??

BtnDeleteSelected.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');");

The confirm dialog appears and if i select "OK" it still does not submit.. Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you should not be returning in all cases.  If you view the source of the page and look for the button markup, you are likely to see this...

```
onclick="return confirm('Ok?'); __doPostback();"
```

The __doPostback invocation is inserted automatically by the ASP.NET framework in some cases.  Since you return immediately regardless of the result of `confirm`, the postback never fires.  The ultimate solution would be to not to set the onclick attribute, but instead use an [unobtrusive approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).  However, if there is pressing reason to control this on the server-side via onclick, you can use a simple `if` statement and only return when they press "Cancel"...

```
string js = "if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) return false;";
BtnDeleteSelected.Attributes.Add("onclick", js);
```

Comment: great thanks! Makes perfect sense. The only pressing need is probably bad habit mixed with laziness.. something i should overcome i know! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too.  I was using adding the client side javascript in the `OnItemCreated` code of a datagrid like this:

```
 myTableCell = e.Item.Cells(iDeleteColumnNumber) 'Delete Button Column
 myDeleteButton = myTableCell.Controls(1)

 If myDeleteButton.UniqueID = "lbtnDelete" Then
    myDeleteButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(!confirm('OK to Delete?'))return false;")
 End If
```

For some reason that didn't work.  I then moved the JavaScript to the `<asp:linkbutton>` in the design view like this:

```
   <asp:LinkButton id="lbtnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="link-text" Text="<img border=0 src=../images/icons/icon-delete.gif alt=Delete>"
 CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="if(!confirm('OK to Delete?'))return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to return TRUE if validation passes? Meaning, if confirm() returns false I don't think the form will submit.

Comment: from what i understand the above is all that is needed.. clicking ok returns true

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK on the surface. Do you have any validators that might be preventing it being submitted? Try adding `BtnDeleteSelected.CausesValidation = false` to prevent the delete button calling any client-side validators.

Comment: i've added BtnDeleteSelected.CausesValidation = false thinking the same thing.. no dice.. there is no other validation on the page.

Comment: Although i am using radgrid with confirms in there.. probably the issue.. but there are no js errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please try calling [doPostBack](http://aspalliance.com/895) function ;)

I mean:

```
BtnDeleteSelected.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckConfirm();");

<script language="javascript">
function CheckConfirm()
{
    if ( confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?') )
        __doPostBack('BtnDeleteSelected','');
    else
        return false;

    return true;
}
</script>
```

Hope that helps,