# Submit button and Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Submit button with code behind that evaluates stuff in c#, the problem is that I also want to add a function in javascript that asks "This file already exists, do you want to replace it?

So my question is how can I trigger both?

```
OnClick="myC#mehod" and also OnClientClick =  return (some javascript);
```

Can I do this?...

Comment: Please don't put "ASP.NET C#" and such in your title. Leave it in the tags, where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

```
deleteBtn.Attributes["onClick"] = 
    "return confirm('This file already exists, do you want to replace it?');"
```

**Updated for clarification;**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReplace" runat="server" onclick="btnReplace_Click" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return confirm('This file already exists, do you want to replace it?');" />

protected void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Replace the File
}
```

Comment: Great and how do I evaluate if they clicked yes or no? something like

if they confirmed = do this if not do nothing

Comment: if it goes to OnClick is which "myC#mehod" then user pressed "OK" otherwise it will stop processing if user pressed "Cancel".

Comment: have you defined the eventhandler for server_click as well? You need both.

Comment: I have one event handler for OnClick="on_Submit", what else do I need? can you elaborate.. I am kind of a newbie thank you

Comment: Thank you Chris, the problem with this is that we are always assuming we want to replace the file but it is based on a condition, if the old file name equals the new file name then it should pop that up....

Comment: Remove the OnClientClick from .aspx and add the original code with a condition check in Page_load in the .aspx.cs

Comment: I need to be able to do something like

if(oldfilename == newfilename)
  pop the message
else
   do not pop

i am having trouble getting this done :(

Comment: I did the first one and it does not pop when i do
if(oldfilename == newfilename)
  deleteBtn.Attributes["onClick"] =      "return confirm('This file already exists, do you want to replace it?');" 
else
   do nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('This file already exists, do you want to replace it?');"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
OnClientClick = "if(!confirm('This file already exists, do you want to replace it?')) return false;"
```

this is more safer than `return` direct

Comment: How so? If they click 'Yes', it returns true. If they click 'No', it returns false; if(!true) return false just adds an additional evaluation and no extra functionality

Comment: I've read it before that if you add `return` at the beginning might makes some problems with some old browsers. I'm just `return`ing based on a condition. If we use `return` at the beginning this means I should return something either false or true and don't continue to the next statement which is the default behavior/code for the button. So some old browsers doesn't understand that then it breaks the method even if it returned true.

Comment: check this post answer to validate my words http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730518/javascript-confirm-asp-net-button-never-submits/3730636#3730636 it is returning in all cases